# A more sophisticated group

Tags: list, haskell, grouping

I want to group a list in a way, that each group is as large as possible and contains at most n distinct values (the grouping is greedy).

For example: `groupN 2 [2,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,4,5]` should be `[[2,2,3],[4,5,5,4],[3,4],[5]]`, `groupN 3 [2,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,4,5]` should be `[[2,2,3,4],[5,5,4,3,4,5]]` and `group = groupN 1`.

I haven't figured out a nice way to implement that. Do you?  The solution should be as generic as possible since I need a bit more conditions on the groups.

Comment: By `n` elements, you mean `n` distinct elements?

Comment: I mean n distinct values. I have edited the question, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by defining a helper function, which takes the appropriate section from the head of the list. Something like

```
splitNDistinct :: (Eq a) => Int -> [a] -> ([a],[a])
splitNDistinct n xs = go 0 [] xs
   where 
     go _ _ [] = ([], [])
     go count seen xs'@(x:xs)
      | x `elem` seen = let (taken, rest) = go count seen xs in (x:taken, rest)
      | count /= n = let (taken, rest) = go (count+1) (x:seen) xs in (x:taken, rest)   
      | otherwise = ([], xs')
```

This gives

```
> splitNDistinct 1 [1, 1,2, 1,2,3, 1,2,3,4]
([1,1],[2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4])
> splitNDistinct 2 [1, 1,2, 1,2,3, 1,2,3,4]
([1,1,2,1,2],[3,1,2,3,4])
> splitNDistinct 3 [1, 1,2, 1,2,3, 1,2,3,4]
([1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3],[4])
> splitNDistinct 4 [1, 1,2, 1,2,3, 1,2,3,4]
([1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4],[])
```

The above function records how many and what elements it's seen before, and then only takes new elements if it has seen it before, or if there is space for new elements.

(The above can possibly be neatened by recognising that the two recursive cases for `go` have almost identical structures except for the difference in the value `count` and in `seen` in the recursive call. Factoring out could easily make the function less clean though.)

`groupN` can be implemented through repeated application of `splitNDistinct`.

---

Just thinking about it, one could define `mapFst f (a,b) = (f a, b)` and replace the `let`-expressions in the recursive calls of `go` with `mapFst (x:) $ go count seen xs` and `mapFst (x:) $ go (count+1) (x:seen) xs` respectively, which makes their similarity even more annoying.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:
As dbaupp notes, I answered a different, simpler question. A proper understanding yields

```
import Data.List
import qualified Data.Set as S

groupN :: Ord a => Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupN n (h:t) = reverse . fmap reverse . fst $
                 foldl' add ([[h]], S.singleton h) t
  where insHead (l:t) i = (i:l):t
        add (l, s) i
          | i `S.member` s = (insHead l i, s)
          | S.size s == n  = ([i]:l, S.singleton i)
          | True           = (insHead l i, S.insert i s)
```

This is (I think) correct and fairly concise, and runs in linear time relative to its input (O(n log m) for groups of m unique values and an input list of length n; the theoretical maximum is O(n) using a data structure with constant-time insert and lookup, and I think dbaupp's runs in O(mn). I do, however, strengthen the condition `Eq a` to `Ord a` by using sets, and sacrifice laziness.

---

The incorrect code:

```
import Data.List

groupN :: Eq a => Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupN n = concatN n . group
  where concatN n l = case splitAt n l of
          (l, [])  -> return $ concat l
          (l1, l2) -> (concat l1):(concatN n l2)
```

You can use `genericSplitAt` to relax the `Int` to an `Integral`.

Comment: I really *really* like this, much better than my ugly solution.. unfortunately it doesn't quite work. `groupN 2 [1,2,1] == [[1,2],[1]]` but should be `[[1,2,1]]`, and for `n >= 2`, `groupN n [1,2] == [[1],[2]]` when it should be `[[1,2]]`.

Comment: (And it also fails on some of the examples in the question.)

Comment: My fault--I simplified the question (this gives n groups, not n distinct groups).

And even by that standard, `(l, []) -> l` should be `(l, []) -> return $ concat l`.